# How to get this text effect? What are the blending settings? Any tutorial?

Tags: photoshop-effects, text, effects

Any idea how to achieve [this exact text effect](http://img580.imageshack.us/img580/7231/howtogetthistexteffect.jpg)?

[image: Text effect]

Does this kind of text effect have a name? I know the moonlight text effect and since I'm new to Photoshop, I do not understand what blending effect settings need to be applied to text.

Detailed instructions on above text effect are highly appreciated.
I would also appreciate if you could direct me to similar text effect tutorials.

Comment: the answer to "Does this kind of text effect have any name?" is almost always "no". Sure terms like "metallic" or "moonlight" or "eroded" might get used, but these don't really mean anything very specific. Work through a few tutorials, but the rest is down to experimentation.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a combination of a few effects. There is an internal gradient, slight embossing, and an outer fine stroke. There may also be a very slight drop shadow on the top one.

Comment: can you help with the settings?

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure about any specific name for that effect, maybe something along the lines of 'Metallic text effect'? Just try running a search for tutorials on this kind of effect, that should provide some useful results!

As for achieving this effect in Photoshop, the steps below should hopefully be of help to you!

**Step 1:** Create a new layer and then the text you want.

**Step 2:** With your text layer selected, go down to the 'Add layer style' button below the layers window (It has a little 'Fx' icon).

**Step 3:** To begin with, choose 'gradient overlay' and click on the small black to white gradient sample you can see. Now pick the two colours you want to include in the gradient.

**Step 4:** You will also need to add a 'Inner Shadow' so select that from the left hand side and make sure the checkbox is also ticked. Use the following settings:

- Blend mode: Normal, Colour: A very light grey
- Opacity: 100%
- Distance: 1px
- Choke: 0%
- Size: 1px

**Step 5:** Now select the 'Drop Shadow' option from the left, again making sure the checkbox is ticked. For this you will need:

- Blend mode: Normal, Colour: Black
- Opacity: 100%
- Distance: 1px
- Spread: 0%
- Size: 7px

Hope this helps! Sorry if its too basic and you were just looking for the right layer style settings, better to be too simple than leave things out :)

Comment: I'm not getting emboss type effect with this. Any idea?

Comment: This answer is missing the Bevel and Emboss effect. It would be a 1 px or 2px Inner Bevel, smooth.